# 'Constructor not found....' error

Tags: java

H. I am getting an error on this piece of code and don't have a clue what to do. Can anyone tell me what the problem could be and how to resolve it.

Error:
No suitable constructor found for Transaction (int, String, double, double(

Code underlined:

```java
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);
```

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainsample;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class TransactionProcess {

    public void deposit(BankAccount bankAccount, double depositAmount) {
    //Get the CurrentBalance
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();

    //First Argument : set the Id of transaction
    //Second Argument : set the Type of Transaction
    //Third Argument : set the TransactionAmount 
    //Fourth Argument : set the Balance Before the transaction (for record purposes)
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);

    if (depositAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
      //Set the updated or transacted balance of bankAccount.
      bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance + depositAmount);
      //then set the MoneyAfterTransaction

      bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
      System.out.println(depositAmount + " has been deposited.");
    }

  }

  // Explanation same as above
  public void withdraw(BankAccount bankAccount, double withdrawAmount) {
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Withdraw", withdrawAmount, currentBalance);

    if (withdrawAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
    } else {
      if (currentBalance < withdrawAmount) {
        System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
      } else {
        bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance - withdrawAmount);        
        bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
        System.out.println(withdrawAmount + " has been withdrawed,");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package mainsample;

/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class Transaction {


  private String transactionType;
  private double transactionAmount;
  private int transactionDate;


  public Transaction() {}

  public Transaction( String transactionType, int transactionDate, double transactionAmount) {

    this.transactionType = transactionType;
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;

  }

  public int getTransactionDate() {
      return transactionDate;
  }

  public void setTransactionDate (int transactionDate) {
      this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
  }


  public String getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
  }

  public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
  }

  public double getTransactionAmount() {
    return transactionAmount;
  }

  public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
  }


  //Override the toString() method of String ? 
  public String toString() {
    return " Transaction Amount : "+ this.transactionAmount +
           " Transaction Type : " + this.transactionType +
           " Transaction Date:  " + this.transactionDate;

  }

}
```

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class BankAccount {
    private int accountId;
    private String holderName;
    private String holderAddress;
    private String openDate;
    private double currentBalance;

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    //Provide Blank Constructor
    public BankAccount(){}

    //Constructor with an arguments.
    public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam,double currentBalance, String holderAdd,String openDate) {
            this.accountId = accountNum;
            this.holderName = holderNam;
            this.holderAddress = holderAdd;
            this.openDate = openDate;
            this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    // Always Provide Setter and Getters
    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {

         this.accountId = accountId;                  
    }
    public String getHolderName() {
        return holderName;
    }
    public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
        this.holderName = holderName;
    }
    public String getHolderAddress() {
        return holderAddress;
    }
    public void setHolderAddress(String holderAddress) {
        this.holderAddress = holderAddress;
    }
    public String getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }
    public void setOpenDate(String openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }

    public double getCurrentBalance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }
    public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction){
      if(transactions.size() >= 6){  // test if the list has 6 or more transactions saved 
      transactions.remove(0);     // if so, then remove the first (it's the oldest)
     }
     transactions.add(transaction); // the new transaction is always added, no matter how many other transactions there are already in the list
     }

    public String toString(){
        return "\nAccount number: " + accountId + 
                "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + 
                "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + 
                "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + 
                "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is no constructor which take four arguments.  The only constructor you gave takes three arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);` This means you are passing `four arguments`.

But you have created `Transaction( String transactionType, int transactionDate, double transactionAmount)` which accepts only `three arguments`.

According to your need I guess you may want to add one more parameter to your constructor definition to store the value `Deposit` or remove it while calling the constructor if you don't need it.

If you want three arguments:

Change the following line of code in your program:

`Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), depositAmount, currentBalance);`

As per my comment below:

> You need to verify the data types of all the parameters you are passing. It certainly means String is needed and you are passing an int. And I doubt if it is regarding the **bankAccount.getTransactions().size()** parameter as **size()** is supposed to give you **int** value but in your constructor you need **String transactionType** String value. You will have to change the types as per your need. *And a hint to convert int value to String you can use String.valueOf();*

Comment: Ok. Understand that. How can it be fixed? I only want three arguments.

Comment: I'm still getting an error with the same code. Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to string.

Comment: @InsideFootball You need to verify the data types of all the parameters you are passing. It certainly means String is needed and you are passing an int. And I doubt if it is regarding the `bankAccount.getTransactions().size()` parameter as `size()` is supposed to give you int value but in your constructor you need `String transactionType` String value. You will have to change the types as per your need. And a hint to convert int value to String you can use `String.valueOf();`

Answer (score 3):

Constructor you have

`Transaction(String, int, double);`

But you are trying to give

```
 Transaction(int, String, int, double);
```

Modify the following,

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);
```

instead of

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);
```

Replace your Transaction class by the following.

```
 public class Transaction {


      private String transactionType;
      private double transactionAmount;
      private double balanceAmount;
      private Date transactionDate;


      public Transaction() {}

      public Transaction( String transactionType, Date transactionDate, double transactionAmount, double balanceAmount) {

        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
        this.balanceAmount = balanceAmount;
     }

       public Transaction( String transactionType, double transactionAmount, double balanceAmount) {

    this.transactionType = transactionType;
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    this.balanceAmount = balanceAmount;

  }

      public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
      }

      public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
      }

      public double getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
      }

      public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
      }


      //Override the toString() method of String ? 
      public String toString() {
        return " Transaction Amount : "+ this.transactionAmount +
               " Transaction Type : " + this.transactionType +
               " Balance Amount : " + this.balanceAmount +
               " Transaction Date:  " + this.transactionDate;

      }

        /**
         * @return the balanceAmount
         */
        public double getBalanceAmount()
        {
            return balanceAmount;
        }

        /**
         * @param balanceAmount the balanceAmount to set
         */
        public void setBalanceAmount(double balanceAmount)
        {
            this.balanceAmount = balanceAmount;
        }

    }
```

Print Transaction method

```
public void printTransaction(int accountNumberId)
  {
      List<Transaction> transactionList = getTransactions(accountNumberId); // this getTransactions() you have to create and fetch all the transaction listed by the holderName

      for(Transaction transaction : transactionList)
      {
          System.out.println("Transaction Amount : "+transaction.getTransactionAmount());
          System.out.println("Transaction Date : "+transaction.getTransactionDate());
          System.out.println("Transaction Type : "+transaction.getTransactionType());
      }
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67126/discussion-on-answer-by-newuser-constructor-not-found-error).

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is that you have following constructor for transaction class:

```
public Transaction() {}
public Transaction( String transactionType, int transactionDate, double transactionAmount)
```

And you are passing 4 argument which doesnt match any of these. Instead try:

```
 Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", 0, depositAmount);
```

As bankAccount has currentBalance details, you dont need to pass those. Also there is no need to pass the size of transaction in your case as i dont see any purpose in your code.